# Tempo para transições ficarem prontas para execução

Tags: javascript, css3

O problema é que, quando eu atribuo uma transição a um elemento já "pintado" no DOM, ela ainda não está pronta para executar na instrução seguinte.

**Vou ilustrar:**

Suponhamos que eu tenho a classe "animar" e nessa classe tem uma transição.

```
.animar {
    transition: all 1s;
}
```

Caso eu atribua essa classe dinamicamente a um elemento do DOM, por meio de Javascript, e queira já usar a transição na instrução seguinte, eu não posso fazer. Seria assim:

```
var elemento = document.querySelector('#qualquercoisa');

// Atribuo a classe que contem a transição
elemento.classList.add('animar');

// Modifico o CSS do elemento, mas ele não é animado. O elemento é movido direto, sem nenhuma transição. 
elemento.style.marginLeft = '300px';
```

**A forma que funciona:**

Para que a transição execute, como é esperado, eu tenho que fazer assim:

```
 // Continuação do código acima
 setTimeout(function() {
   elemento.style.marginLeft = '600px';
 }, 10);
```

**Ou seja:** a transição só é executada se eu der um tempo depois de atribuir a classe, e então, setar as modificações de estilo que eu queira. Seria uma espécia de "tempo para o browser processar".

Eu fiquei encucado com isso, porque, como eu vou saber o tempo necessário para que o browser esteja pronto para executar uma animação naquele elemento? Não é possível que esse seja o jeito mais apropriado de fazer isso. 
Alguém poderia apontar alguma solução? Ou melhor: o jeito certo, porque eu cheguei nisso sozinho e tenho quase certeza que está errado... =P

Obrigado.

Comment: Porque é que não tens logo `300px` no CSS, para depois animar para `600px`?

Comment: @Sergio Acho que não entendeu o problema. Do 0 para o 300 é onde está o bug, é onde o elemento não é animado. Eu apenas mudei para 600 para ilustrar que, depois do setTimeout, o elemento é animado normalmente do 300 até o 600.

Comment: @Sergio Havia também um erro no comentário do código. Era pra ser "Ele NÃO é animado". Corrigi.

Comment: _"Do 0 para o 300 é onde está o bug"_ - ok, mas tens no CSS algum valor inicial para `margin-left` (no CSS)?

Comment: @Sergio Não. O valor é o padrão; 0px.

Comment: @Sergio E isso não é um "código real", é só uma ilustração de um problema que já tenho há algum tempo.

Comment: Tens de iniciar no CSS, o valor inicial não é `0` é "não defenido"

Comment: @Sergio Vou analisar melhor, porque eu estou com esse problema em arquivos locais, mas no JSFiddle rodou, com e sem setar um valor inicial. https://jsfiddle.net/zjnk1usk/

Comment: Ok, se conseguires reproduzir o problema no jsFiddle diz para eu dar uma olhada também.

Comment: @Sergio Na verdade o problema todo é esse mesmo. Eu fiz o mesmo código localmente e não funcionou. A div já aparece na posição 300px. OBS: Como é só Front-end, não está em localhost; é link direto para o arquivo.

Comment: E se deres valor inicial no teu projeto não funciona?

Comment: @Sergio Não. Eu tentei.

Comment: Testa, antes de usar JavaScript fazer `console.log(window.getComputedStyle(elemento).marginLeft);`. O que dá?

Comment: @Sergio Dá "0px". Mas olha só: só de por essa instrução entre o querySelecor e o style.marginLeft, a animação rodou.

Comment: Ok, eu estava convencido que o browser não setava o `0px` como valor inicial. Se isso acontece então o problema é que o browser é "poupado" no repaint espera antes de adicionar a classe para fazer várias coisas ao mesmo tempo. Não podes juntar essa classe do inicio?

Comment: @Sergio Não, porque eu preciso alternar entre animar e não animar quando seto posições diferentes para o elemento. Mas a "solução" do setTimeout parece funcionar. Obrigado por sua atenção. Boa noite.

Comment: Sim o setTimeout é uma maneira válida. outra variante seria mudar o `style.transitionDuration` para zero e depois repor.

Answer (score 0):

Para verificar quando a animação terminar, adicione `addEventListener` ao elemento que irá chamar um `callback`:

```
var div = document.querySelector('#div')
div.classList.add('animar');
div.style.marginLeft = '300px';
div.addEventListener("webkitTransitionEnd", callBack,false);
div.addEventListener("transitionend", callBack,false);
div.addEventListener("otransitionend", callBack,false);
```

```js
window.onload = function(){
 var div = document.querySelector('#div')
 div.classList.add('animar');
 div.style.marginLeft = '300px';
 div.addEventListener("webkitTransitionEnd", callBack,false);
 div.addEventListener("transitionend", callBack,false);
 div.addEventListener("otransitionend", callBack,false);
}

function callBack(){
 alert("Fim");
}
```

```css
.animar {
    transition: all 1s;
}

#div {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 background: red;
  }
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```